# How to convert ARRAY<DATE> and DATE to a common format?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm creating a table with, first of all, all dates from 2022 and 2023 and then a further set of random dates from these years. I'm trying to UNION two queries but getting the following error `Column 1 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: ARRAY<DATE>, DATE`. I understand the first query returns an array of dates while the other just dates and I need to CAST one of them to the type of another for this to work. I tried to cast in either direction but getting all the time errors about invalid casts. How can I do this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dataset.table AS(
  SELECT GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', '2023-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS Date_stop,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(CAST(start + (finish - start) * RAND() AS INT64)) random_date
  FROM (SELECT 500 ids_count, DATE '2022-01-01' start_date, DATE '2023-12-31' finish_date), 
  UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, ids_count)) id,
  UNNEST([STRUCT(UNIX_DATE(start_date) AS start, UNIX_DATE(finish_date) AS finish)])
)
```

Comment: An array is a list of objects, which will be held in a single field in a single record in your table. How do you expect an array and a single date value to be compatible data types?

Comment: you seem to want this : `SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', '2023-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Date_stop`,

Comment: @Jaytiger thank you, swapping the first code with what you proposed did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Appears that @Jaytiger's suggestion is correct, Making this suggestion as a community wiki for better visibility. As such the query resolves the incompatible type error by replacing the line in question:

> SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-01-01', '2023-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS Date_stop